# How to split an string inside a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

new to the stackoverflow community, so do be forgiving if I've done anything incorrect. As I'm an amateur in coding in php, I'm currently facing a difficulty in multi dimensional arrays.

Currently, I have this array being returned to me.

```
Array(
    [trialID] => 1
    [trialMixedArray] => 1,2,3,4,5,6
    [trialStatus] => active
    [trialAddedDate] => 2017-11-13 09:56:03
)
```

How do I split the trialMixedArray and return it to the original array so that it becomes formatted to be like the following result:

```
Array(
    [trialID] => 1
    [trialMixedArray] => Array(
                               [0] => 1
                               [1] => 2
                               [2] => 3
                               [3] => 4
                               [4] => 5
                               [5] => 6
    [trialStatus] => active
    [trialAddedDate] => 2017-11-13 09:56:03
)
```

Thanks for the help in advance! Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `explode` function, which splits string to array. [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

`$results['trialMixedArray'] = explode(',', $results['trialMixedArray']);`

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
$finalArray = [];
fetchItems($array_variable) {
  foreach($array_variable as $item){
    if(is_array($item) {
      fetchItems($item);
    } else {
      $finalArray[] = $item;
    }
  }
}

fetchItems($originaArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use explode function to split any string based on a key.

The syntax is explode('key',string);